# Terminology "Invariance of the Boundary"

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, manifolds, terminology

This terminology question has always tripped me up: If $M$ is a topological manifold with boundary, the (nontrivial!) result that $\partial M$ and $\operatorname{Int}{M}$ are disjoint is called "Invariance of the Boundary" (at least in John Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*). Why this name? When I see the word "invariance" I think of a property unchanged by a mapping. For example, "invariance of the boundary", to me, would mean something more like "If $M$ and $N$ are manifolds with boundary and $f : M \to N$ is a homeomorphism, then $\partial M = \partial N$ and $\operatorname{Int}{M} = \operatorname{Int}{N}$." But we don't need the fact that the boundary and interior of a manifold are disjoint to prove this.

Is there another reason why we call the disjointness result "invariance of the boundary"?

Comment: that is exactly the point: the proposed theorem you state is true, and this justifies our terminology for interior and boundary points of a manifold (because if $p$ is a boundary point relative to one chart, then the same holds with respect to any other chart whose domain contains $p$). Otherwise, one could not make a distinction between these two types of points. In the topological case, this is pretty hard, but in the smooth case, this is a consequence of the inverse function theorem.